# How to save boolean value in to database while pressing html button using django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

How to save the boolean value as true to database also route to another page. While we press continue button to save True value to db using django model also route to another page as welcome page.

```
#models.py
class Tutorial(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_tutorial = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('tutorial'), default=False)

#views.py
def tutorial_page(request):
   return render(request, "home/tutorial_page.html")

#urls.py
from . import views as homeview
path('tutorial-page/', homeview.tutorial_page)


#tutorialpage.html  
<article>
    <h2>demo</h2>
    <p>press <a href="https://localhost:8000/welcomepage/">continue</a> to skip the tutorial on next time </p>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find tutorial model by user and update it like this

```
#models.py
class Tutorial(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_tutorial = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('tutorial'), default=False)

#views.py
def tutorial_page(request):
   return render(request, "home/tutorial_page.html")

def welcomepage(request):
    tutorial = Tutorial.objects.filter(user=user).first()
    if tutorial:
        tutorial.is_tutorial = True
        tutorial.save()
    return render(request, "home/welcomepage.html")


#urls.py
from . import views as homeview
path('tutorial-page/', homeview.tutorial_page)
path('welcomepage/', homeview.welcomepage)


#tutorialpage.html
<article>
    <h2>demo</h2>
    <p>press <a href="https://localhost:8000/welcomepage/">continue</a> to skip the tutorial on next time </p>
</article>


#welcomepage.html 
<article>
    <h2>You are welcome!</h2>
</article>
```